# put recyclerview's scrollbar at the end of the parent layout android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following layout. Currently the scrollbar is coming above the layout of the arrows but I need to place scrollbar at the bottom of the layout i.e below the layout of the arrows. I tried using the `scrollbarStyle` in `Recyclerview` but it didn't work out. Any suggestion on how to overcome this problem?

[image]

My layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:minHeight="@dimen/size_94dp"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:clickable="true"
          bind:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/listLayout"
          bind:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          android:background="@color/white"
          bind:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listLayout"
          >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            bind:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            bind:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            bind:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            bind:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/arrow_layout"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/custom_scrollbar"
            bind:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/arrow_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            bind:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            bind:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            bind:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_24dp"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
              android:layout_gravity="end"/>
        </FrameLayout>


      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There are a few quick but not as pretty solutions for this, like adding bottom margin to items and constrainting arrows to bottom of recyclerview, however, I would not do that, only if I would not have time, due to deadline or smthing.

Comment: Any other solution can you think off?

Comment: No, at the moment I could not think any better for that, I did not post the previous as an answer because it is just a be fast, be done solution. However, I would like to know the proper solution for this. It wont be that ugly if you create a custom view for that, but if it is a single case it is a little bit overkill.

Comment: We could use something like custom `ItemDecoration`. But not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @tynn I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a Constraint layout, which is already designed to easily overlap items. The simplest fix in that case is to **add padding at the bottom of your RV  and then constrain the arrows to overlap the padding area**.

Contrary to some comments made above, there is nothing wrong with that approach - a custom view (or a custom layout manager) would be overkill when you are not adding and new predefined behaviour and will take much more work. If you do still want to take that approach you're going to need a seek bar and recycler to work together, which sounds to me like an easy way to introduce bugs

**Edit**: it should be as simple as adding `android:paddingBottom="25dp"` to the *root* view of your RecyclerView item layout (the layout you pass to your ViewHolder) and then changing your FrameLayout to:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/arrow_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        bind:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerView"
        bind:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/recyclerView"
        bind:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/recyclerView"
        android:marginBottom="16dp">
```

As Barotia mentioned you can always change the 25dp and 16dp to any value you want, including percentages

Comment: In that case, won't the items in the `Recyclerview` overlap with the arrows in smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Well the idea with a constraint layout is that items are in the same position relative to eachother, regardless of screen size. If you don't set absolute heights/widths, you should have no problem

Comment: “constraints to overlap the padded area”. How to achieve that ?

Comment: I'll add code to the answer from a computer later - but basically match left, right, bottom constraints of the arrows to the rv. Then set bottom margin of the arrows big enough to expose the scrollbar

Comment: I will try it out. But if possible do add some code to replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Another good part of constraintlayout, that you can add widths and heights with percent values, so you do not have to fear that something wont work on smaller screens.